# Relative path for compileroptions in .NET

Tags: .net, deployment, web-config, cruisecontrol.net

I want to use the compileroptions tag in the web.config to version my DLL files. Is it possible to use a relative path? If not, are there any options for using a relative path? I am using [CruiseControl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl).

```
 <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
                      extension=".cs"
                      warningLevel="4"
                      compilerOptions="NEED_ARELATIVE_PATH\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
                      type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion"
                                value="v4.0"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError"
                                value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a precompiled web application, the source is copied to the obj subdirectory of the precompiled root, so you can use

```
compilerOptions="obj\Release\Source\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
```

(You have to include the active configuration (e.g., `Release`) in the string, but at least it's a relative path.)

Comment: How can I find the "active configuration" path? I tried "obj\Release\Source\AssemblyInfo.cs" with the "AssemblyInfo.cs" file located at the project root (same folder as web.config), but it still does not find the file. Absolute path works fine but it´s too bad for maintenance...

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it doesn´t seem to work, and it seems that the correct answer must be related to the use of some system variable to reference the application path.